# How to create an Observable from simple values using rx extensions for F#?

Tags: f#, rx.net

Currently, I have a function that receives raw data from the outside, process it, and sends it to a callback:

```ml
let Process callback rawData =
    let data = rawData //transforming into actual data....
    callback data
```

callback is a function `'T -> unit`. In my case specifically, it's the `Post` function of a MailboxProcessor (being called like `Process mailbox.Post rawData`)
The process function is called multiple times, and each time I push the processed data into the mailbox queue. So far so good.

Now I want to change this code in a way I can publish this processed data to various consumers, using the rx extensions for FSharp (FSharp.Control.Reactive). This means that `callback` will be either an Observable, or a function that publishes to subscribers. How do I do this?

I found two options:

1. Create a class that implements IObservable, and pass that object to the `Process` function. I'd like to avoid creating classes if possible.
2. Use the `Subject.behavior`. This does exactly what I want, except it requires a initial state, which doesnt make sense semantically in this case, and apparently Subjects are frowned upon (from a link in the ReactiveX site http://davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx).

What would be the better way, from a functional programming perspective? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one idea: You can use an object expression to implement `IObservable<_>` without the overhead of an explicit class:

```
let createObservable subscribe =
    {
        new IObservable<_> with
            member __.Subscribe(observer) =
                subscribe observer
    }
```

To use this, specify a `subscribe` function of type `IObserver<_> -> IDisposable`. No classes needed.

Comment: This is probably not a good idea. Implementing an observable with correct Rx semantics is hard and it's always recommended to use Rx's built-ins.

Comment: You’re probably right, but this is why I dislike the reactive paradigm. Too much magic.

Comment: It's more of making concurrent code safe to write, which requires a lot of checks and balances - Rx as a monad abstracts away threading and concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `observe { .. }` computation builder works, but there is a function in the `FSharp.Control.Reactive` library that does the same thing:

```
open FSharp.Control.Reactive
let obs = Observable.ofSeq [1;2;3;4;5]
```

If I was using the `observe { .. }` computation builder, I'd also use the fact that it supports `for` loop, which makes your code a bit simpler:

```
let Process initialData = observe {
  for x in initialData do yield x }
```

Comment: I used a Sequence in my answer to exemplify, but in my real use case the data comes from a NetworkStream. I think I have to use `observe` in this case. Good to know though!

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Fsharp reactive provides the keyword `observe` from the module `FSharp.Control.Reactive.Builders`. This allows you to create ad-hoc observables:

```
open FSharp.Control.Reactive.Builders

//In my real case, "initialData" is a byte stream and 
//at each step I read a few bytes off of it
let Process initialData =
    let rec loop data =
        observe {
            match data with
            | x :: xs ->
                yield x
                yield! loop xs
            | [] -> ()
        }
    loop initialData

let obs = Process ([1;2;3;4;5])
obs.Subscribe(fun d -> printfn "Consumer A: %A" d) |> ignore
obs.Subscribe(fun d -> printfn "Consumer B: %A" d) |> ignore
Threading.Thread.Sleep 1000
obs.Subscribe(fun d -> printfn "Late consumer: %A" d) |> ignore
```

Important to note that this creates a *cold* observable, so the Late consumer receives all events.